# REST API for a game

Tags: angularjs, spring, rest, web-services, web

I am developing a web distributed application to let any user to play the Klondike (solitaire) game. I want to develop a API REST but I am not sure how the resources URL should look like.

At the server, I have the 'game', 'stock', 'waste', 'tableau', 'foundation' classes among others. The game class has the method moveFromStockToWaste, moveFromTableauToTableu... which implements the movements of the game.

What I have read about REST API is that the resources URL should look like a hierarchy of nouns while the operations (verbs) over this nouns are the HTTP methods (GET, PUT, POST, PATCH). 
I am not sure if the way to move a card from stock to waste via API REST should look like this though moveFromTableauToTableau resource is a verb and not a noun:

```
 UPDATE /player/{playerId}/game/{gameId}/moveFromTableauToTableau
```

Other way I have though is having this tableau piles cards resources:

```
 URL: /player/{playerId}/game/{gameId}/TableauPile/1/
```

than in turn have resources like the number of not upturned cards and the upturned cards (all the information needed about the tableaus).
Then update this tableau pile resource by deleting the last card:

```
DELETE /player/{playerId}/game/{gameId}/TableauPile/1/upTurnedCard/3
```

And then put the card deleted in the target passing the new card suit and value:

```
POST /player/{playerId}/game/{gameId}/TableauPile/3/upTurnedCard
```

But this way the REST API would let to move a card from the tableau to the waste and this is not a valid movement.

Answer (score 1):

I always think designing a REST API as a pretty uneasy task.

The second approach seems cleaner in naming convention terms, but I think you should never compromise the integrity of your targeted system to be compliant with such things. As you allow making one atomic operation in two http calls, it is in fact no longer atomic and you expose your system to unpredictable state in case of network failure or if any call fail for some reason. Avoid this kind of problem must be the top priority.

One idea could be thinking moves in terms of moves collection. So for a game you have a moves ressources. And then you can refine the move nature with some additional request parameters such like

```
POST/players/{playerId}/games/{gameId}/moves?type=TABLEAU_TO_TABLEAU
Body: 
{
  "src": "stock",
  "dest": "waste"
}
```

This way you should have enough flexibilty to handle the different types of move.

Besides, may I suggest you to use plural form for resource naming :

player -> players

game -> games

so

GET /players naturally means give me all values of the player resource

GET /players/1 means give me the player of the players resource with the restriction playerId=1

Comment: So in your proposal move would be a resource and its representation is a JSON with data with the origin and target of the move, and then the client change the resource by updating the representation of this move and some representations are forbidden (some combinations of origin and target). Have I understand it right?. Then how the client perform the move after choosing it? Just updating this resource the move should be performed?

Comment: Yes that's it. In the underlying service layer you can exclude forbidden moves. Also you can publish a GET /players/{playerId}/games/{gameId}/moves to return all the legal moves according to the game state. Yes just update the move ressource. I guess you can switch PUT to POST. It may have a better meaning as you create a new move on the game. So it's a POST. I edited my answer.

Answer (score 1):

> I am developing a web distributed application to let any user to play the Klondike (solitaire) game. I want to develop a API REST but I am not sure how the resources URL should look like.

Oracle: how would you implement this as a website?

> At the server, I have the 'game', 'stock', 'waste', 'tableau', 'foundation' classes among others. The game class has the method moveFromStockToWaste, moveFromTableauToTableu... which implements the movements of the game.

One important thing to realize is that the classes in your implementation *don't matter*; REST is about manipulating documents, the changes that happen to the game are side effects of manipulating the "documents".

In other words, the REST API is a mask that your game wears so that it looks like a web site.

See Jim Webber's talk [DDD In the Large](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aQVSzMV8DWc).

[Klondike](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Klondike_(solitaire)) is effectively a state machine; any given tableau has some limited number of legal moves to make, each of which takes you to a new position.

So one way you might model the API is a representation of the tableau plus affordances (links) for each move, and the game progresses from one state to the next as you follow the links that describe a possible legal move.

There are "only" 8*10^67 or so deals to worry about, and for each of them you effectively have a graph of all of the reachable positions, and order them by traversal order, and then just link them all together.

```
/76543210987654321098765432109876543210987654321098765432109876543210/0
/76543210987654321098765432109876543210987654321098765432109876543210/1
/76543210987654321098765432109876543210987654321098765432109876543210/2
/76543210987654321098765432109876543210987654321098765432109876543210/3
```

And so on.

It's not an [impossible](http://bridge.thomasoandrews.com/impossible/) arrangement, although it may be impractical, and since the URL describes the entire state of the game, the player has access to hidden state.

I'd suggest first trying this approach on something less complicated, like [tic-tac-toe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tic-tac-toe).

Hiding the state is relatively straight forward, because the mapping of the current game to a specific seed can be done on the server.  That is, you send a POST to the start game end point, and that generates some random identifier, and maps the random identifier to a seed position, and off you go.

But a potential problem in this design is that HTTP is a stateless protocol; there's no way for the server to "know", when the player requests `GET /games/000/152`, that the client was previously in a position that could legally move to position 152.  You can make the URI [hard to guess](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2013/05/01/rest-lesson-learned-avoid-hackable-urls/), but that's about it.

What you likely *want* is the ability to ensure that the moves made by the player are legal, which means that the server needs to be tracking the current state of the game, and the player gets a view of the open information only.

The simplest HTML model of this would have the representation of the game show the information that the player is allowed, and a form with a list of the legal moves.  The player selects one move and submits the form, which is a POST back to the game resource (directly back to the same resource, because we want the cache invalidation properties).  Your implementation could then check that the received move is legal, refresh its own local state, and send an appropriate response.

That's the basic pattern we should be considering; GET the game, then send an [unsafe request](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-4.2.1) to modify the server's copy of the game.

The basic plan isn't all that different if you want to use a remote authoring approach.  GET fetches a representation of the revealed information, the client makes legal edits to that representation, and PUTs the new representation to the same URL.  The server verifies that the new position is reachable from the old position, and accepts the move, using its own copy of the hidden information to update the representation of the player's view.

(Pay careful attention to the meta data used in the response to [PUT](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-4.2.4); the server is supposed to be communicating carefully whether the new representation is adopted as is, or if the server has transformed the proposed representation to make it consistent with the server's constraints).

You could, of course, also use [PATCH](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5789) to communicate the changes made to the representation by the client.

If messages were lost, or duplicated, the client's view and the server's view might not be aligned.  So you may want to have your representation of the game include a clock/timer/turn number, so that the server can be certain that the players move is intended for the current state of the game.

**EDIT** As Roman notes, HTTP already has built into it the concept of *[validators](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7232#section-2)*, which allow you to lift data from your domain specific clock into the headers, so that generic components can understand and act appropriately to [conditional requests](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7232)

Another way of thinking about the game is to consider [event sourcing](https://martinfowler.com/eaaDev/EventSourcing.html); the client and the server are taking turns appending entries to a [log](https://engineering.linkedin.com/distributed-systems/log-what-every-software-engineer-should-know-about-real-time-datas-unifying), and the view of the game itself is computed by applying the events in the log.  The client's moves would be limited to the set that manipulate the open information, the server's moves would reveal previously hidden information.

So you could use [Atom Pub](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5023), or something very similar to it, to write new entries into the log.  This in effect gives you two different representations of the game - the view, that shows you what you see when you look at the tableau, and the feed, which shows you the moves made to reach that point.

(If you squint, you'll see that this is really just a variation on "let the client pick a legal move".)

You *could*, I suppose, treat each of the elements in your domain model as a resource, and try to design an API to allow the client to manipulate those directly, but it isn't at all clear to me what benefit you get from that.

Comment: Just to append on this detailed answer, the "clock/time/turn" mechanism could be implemented on top of conditional requests via ETag or If-Modified-Since headers (or the like) to reuse an already established form of concurrency mechanism already available in HTTP. This answers also showcases that there is more to REST than just exposing a DB model via HTTP.